# Usar meu programa para abrir um determinado arquivo

Tags: android, android-manifest

Estou tentando fazer que meu app seja uma opção (ou padrão) na abertura de um arquivo.

Este é o menu manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Arquivos"/>
    <activity android:name=".NomeSenha" />
    <activity android:name=".Bateria" />
    <activity android:name=".Tensao"/>
</application>
```

Comment: Esta pergunta já foi feita e parece que foi você mesmo quem fez, e já tem uma boa resposta. É mais facil tirar dúvidas nos comentários da resposta de la.

Comment: Me desculpem, sou novo nessa ferramenta e não notei de que a primeira pergunta havia sido publicada.